# Pattern annotation not working on Business Model in Java

Tags: java

I have a model -

```
package com.somecompany.gis.businessmodel;

import javax.validation.constraints.Pattern;

public class SearchParameters {

//Check if a valid URL 

@Pattern(regexp = "(https?:\\/\\/(?:www\\.|(?!www))[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\\.[^\\s]{2,}|www\\.[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\\.[^\\s]{2,}|https?:\\/\\/(?:www\\.|(?!www))[a-zA-Z0-9]\\.[^\\s]{2,}|www\\.[a-zA-Z0-9]\\.[^\\s]{2,})")
String endPoint;

}
```

I have a controller endpoint -

```
@RequestMapping(value="/search",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public Map<String,Object> search(@Valid @RequestBody SearchParameters searchParameters){
    //Do something
}
```

I was expecting `@Pattern` to kick in and give error on Validation error by Jackson. But that is not happening. The regex accepts only valid URLs. What am I doing wrong ?

Dependencies included -

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-parser</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.35</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.json-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.4</version>
    </dependency>   
</dependencies>
```

These are my dependencies in project

Comment: You don't seem to be including a validator anywhere (the default with Boot is `hibernate-validator`).

Answer (score 0):

Please check it in this way:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/search",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public Map<String,Object> search(@Valid @RequestBody SearchParameters searchParameters, BindingResult bindingResult){

    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return "errorPage";
    }
    //Do something
}
```

bindingResult object you can use for and retrieve validation errors.

Look at this URL: https://spring.io/guides/gs/validating-form-input/

Comment: Any way of doing it without BindingResult? and also show which field has error ?

Comment: Thymeleaf 
<tr>
   <td>Name:</td>
   <td><input type="text" th:field="*{name}" /></td>
   <td th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('name')}" th:errors="*{name}">Name Error</td>
</tr>